# UIView has zero width and height even though it's visible

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, subclass

I have created a subclass of `UIView` and called it `MSMobileControlView`. I added a `UIView` object to my Autolayout-enabled storyboard, and assigned it's class to `MSMobileControlView`.

Inside `MSMobileControlView` I have this code:

```
-(void)didMoveToSuperview
{
    NSLog(@"self.frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));

    UIBUtton *levelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [levelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 40)];
    [levelButton setTitle:@"Next Level" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self addSubview:levelButton];
}
```

The `NSLog` output is:

```
self.frame: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

However I can still see the view on the screen and the button responds to taps as expected. I have no other code associated with `MSMobileControlView`.
What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Auto Layout runtime is assigning values to the frame later. If you want to see those assigned values, put your `NSLog` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

If there's one piece of advice I would give you when starting out with Auto Layout, it is to forget frames. Just work with constraints. Let Auto Layout manipulate the frames on your behalf to give you the layout that your constraints specify.

Comment: Thanks for the tip: yes, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` works. Is there a delegate that is run within the UIView class when this happens?

Comment: No delegates. Just overriding and invoke super where appropriate. Make sure you set up constraints in updateConstraints (for views) and set translatesAutoResizingIntoConstraints to NO for any programmatically created views

Answer (score 0):

You can check size in layoutSubviews delegate method within UIView class (called multiple times)

and
override method didMoveToWindow and call super.didMoveToWindow() - it will trigger layoutSubviews after frames of all subviews would be correct